# read delimited file from pl sql procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new to pl sql and trying to read a file(column wise),where file(abc.txt) has data delimited by pipe "|" like as below:

```
 first test|add|123
 second test|mod|654
```

So my requirement is like

- How can we read above file in a pl sql procedure.

working sample code will be very helpful.

and below code i used for reading a file:

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE 
    V1 VARCHAR2(200);
    F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    V1 VARCHAR2(200);
    F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
BEGIN 
    F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('USER_DIR','abc.txt','R');

    LOOP
        BEGIN
            UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F1,V1);
            dbms_output.put_line(V1);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN no_data_found THEN EXIT;
        END;
    END LOOP;

    IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F1) THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('File is Open');
    end if;
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F1);
 END;
/
```

Comment: You are better off with a ETL package which can read file and also apply bunch of transformations. Alternatively, you may also opt for BULK LOAD if that's what you wish to do.

Comment: can you please provide any working sample pl sql code.i tried doing with pl sql procedure,but not getting it right.

Comment: Hi Mayur - if you want to read data directly from a file then you can use the UTL_FILE PL/SQL package.  Alternatively you can load data into a table using SQL*Loader, or you can define your file as a External Table.  There are many examples of all these techniques available on the internet.

Comment: @Christian I have added the code which i tried for reading a file,but not getting how to read particular column from a file abc.txt.

Comment: It would probably be easier to define an [external table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm). Otherwise you'll need to read the file line by line and split the fields out manually.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: [`sqlloader`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ)

1. create a table for incoming data
2. define your "loading rules":

   ```
   Use LOAD DATA
     infile '/yourappli/utl_file/abc.txt'
         REPLACE
         INTO TABLE LOAN_BALANCE_MASTER_INT
         fields terminated by '|' optionally enclosed by '"'
         (
           Col_1,
           Col_2,
           Col_3
         )
   ```

## Solution 2: Turn each of your delimited string into a collection

Here is how you can loop trough your delimited string **`V1`** in your code, with the **`cto_table` function declared from the documentation link**:

```
DECLARE 
  V1 VARCHAR2(200);
  F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN 
  F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('USER_DIR','abc.txt','R');
  Loop
  BEGIN
    UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F1,V1);
      for x in ( 
        select column_value a from  table(cto_table('|', V1) )
      ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(x.a);
      end loop;
  EXCEPTION WHEN No_Data_Found 
   THEN EXIT; 
  END;
  end loop;
  IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F1) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('File is Open');
  end if;
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F1);
END;
/
```